# What's the Parse "Object" column type for?

Tags: parse-platform

I see a column type of "Object" when I tried to add a new column to a class in the Parse data browser. What is it for and when do I use that?

Answer (score 1):

This is a object similar to what you would refer to as type "id" when using variables in Objective-C. It is simply another type of variable that Parse is capable of storing. The type definition is given in [this article](http://rypress.com/tutorials/objective-c/data-types/primitives) under the heading "Objective-C Primitives"

Comment: thanks for the answer. not familiar with Objective-C. So "object" is like a pointer to an arbitrary object? Still not following when it could be useful and how it can be used. Is it for Object-C only?

Comment: I don't believe that it is unique to objective c, as Parse supports many different languages that all must use that same selection of column types. Sorry I answered in the context of iOS, totally slipped my mind that parse is used by so many other platforms!